# Internet Gateway Custom Metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there anyway possible to create a  **Custom Metric** for **Internet Gateway**  in AWS?
When I looked at the documentation , I could see that IGW doesn't send any metrics to CloudWatch. Being a managed entity, Is there a way possible for Customers to create a Metric on IGW? or is it that all the metrics that is of interest from IGW should be derived from one of the other services?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out, there are no metrics for IGW. This could be because you [don't pay](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html) for it itself.

But obviously you pay for the traffic out of your VPC. As a surrogate measure of this, you can use NAT gateway, as [NAT gateways have](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway-cloudwatch.html) its own cloudwatch metrics. Depending on your VPC setup, NAT monitoring would be only useful if most of your traffic originates from **private subnets**. If you have resources in public subnets, you would have to measure them individually. For example, load balances have metrics for network traffic as well.

Therefore, creating a custom metric based on, for example, NAT gateway and load balancer metrics should be possible. This would be the closest to proper metrics for IGW I can think of. This does not include solutions based on proxing every traffic through some custom proxy instances.